# Identifiying the componentes of this conditional sentence

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, condicional

I am a native Spanish speaker and forgot most of the grammar rules. The next is a sentence from a test on conditionals.

> Si fuese a San Francisco, me montaría en un barco que me **llevara** a Alcatráz

As I understood from a video this is a conditional of type III.

My question: why is the verb **llevar** in *imperfecto del subjuntivo*?

For me it sounds right, but my non-native speaker friend asked me why not "*un barco que me **llevaría***". I couldn't answer, but it sounds wrong or incomplete if the later is used.

If you could, I would deeply appreciate an analysis of the sentence!

Comment: Your friend is right. Same in English. would take a boat to Alcatras. Its conditional in both.

Answer (score 1):

Toda la última parte queda encapsulada por el ‘que’. Esta partícula inicia una cláusula subordinada que funciona como adjetivo. Una opción sería reemplazarlo por otra cosa:

> Si fuese a San Francisco, me montaría en un barco **caro**.

Es decir, si bien es un verbo, no está funcionando como *el* verbo de la oración. Entonces la estructura quedaría:

> [[Si fuese a San Francisco] [me montaría en un barco [que me llevara a Alcatráz]]]

- ‘Si fuese a San Francisco’: prótasis
- ‘me montaría en un barco que me llevara a alcatraz’: apódosis
- ‘que me llevara a alcatraz’: subordinada adjetiva

En cuanto a por qué el subjuntivo en ‘llevara’, básicamente es para concordar con el resto de la oración ya que la situación planteada es hipotética. Otra opción válida sería: ‘que me lleve a Alcatraz’. Y en cuanto al uso del condicional ‘llevaría’, es igualmente válido pero suena muy cacofónico.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence:

Si fuese/fuera a San Francisco, me subiría a ("montarse en un barco" does not sound natural to me) un barco que me llevara/lleve a Alcatraz.

both "llevara" and "lleve" are correct because, as explained in the other answer, the situation is hypothetical. "Llevaría" sounds off because it would be equivalent to a backshifted future, and the sentence conveys no such certainty.

In a conditional sentence combining present and future, a relative in the future tense (instead of present subjunctive) will also convey certainty (2):

1. Si voy a San Francisco, me subiré a un barco que me lleve a Alcatraz (a ship bound for Alcatraz).
2. Si voy a San Francisco, me subiré a un barco que me llevará a Alcatraz (I will board a ship that will take me to Alcatraz).
3. Si iba a San Francisco (= Cada vez que iba), me subía a un barco que me llevara a Alcatraz (I would board/used to board a ship that would take me to Alcatraz).
4. Si fuera a San Francisco, me subiría a un barco que me lleve/llevara a Alcatraz (same translation with "would board" as above, though in Spanish the conditional does not work well).

To sum up, "que me lleve a Alcatraz" works both in unreal (4) and real (1) contexts, "que me llevara a Alcatraz" works in unreal (4) or past (3) contexts, and "que me llevará/llevaría a Alcatraz" works in real or future contexts (2/3).

Comment: Un par de apuntes: en España puedes "montarte" en cualquier vehículo de tracción animal o mecánica. Supongo que partiendo de "montar a caballo", hemos seguido aplicándolo a cualquier cosa, incluyendo un barco. Por otro lado no acaba de convencerme ninguna de las explicaciones. Si establecemos una separación entre las frases: "Si fuera a San Francisco, me montaría en un barco. El barco me llevaría a Alcatraz y vería el amanecer desde allí", parece perfectamente válido. ¿Porqué si acortamos "llevaría" debería cambiar de forma verbal? A mí me parece correcto "llevase/llevara/llevaría".

Comment: Ok por "montarse". Ref. los tiempos verbales, entiendo tu razonamiento, pero justamente el potencial funciona bien si se inicia una nueva oración: Si eso ocurriera, el barco me llevaría a Alcatraz. Para mí, "subiría a un barco que me llevaría a Alcatraz" en el contexto de una oración condicional suena forzado justamente porque no se sabe si la persona subirá al barco: subiría a un barco y ese barco indefectiblemente me llevaría a Alcatraz. Para mí, el uso de un subjuntivo en la relativa suena mejor. Se trata de una disquisición más pragmática que gramatical, difícil de documentar.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en tus apreciaciones. Básicamente quería resaltar ese último punto, la dificultad de documentar porque suena más correcto "llevara/llevase" que "llevaría" cuando es válido en el mismo contexto pero cambiando ligeramente la frase.